# После обращения к Камере убивается приложение

Tags: android, android-intent

Android убивает приложение при запуске Intent.
В приложении есть кнопка "Сделать фото", которая обращается к камере:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
if (intent.resolveActivity(fragment.getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {//Если есть камера
  Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(fragment.getActivity(), getFileProvider(), nameFileImage);
  intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
  fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}
```

Результат надеюсь получить в onActivityResult.
Но пока я делаю фото, Android убивает приложение, а после фотографии оно стартует, но уже без результата работы с камерой.

Как можно обработать такую ситуацию, чтобы приложение все равно получило результат работы камеры?

**Дополнительно:** Intent вызывается из Fragment.

**Дополнительно 2:** Log не прикладываю, что-то сложно доставать полный.
Причина убийства приложения - мало памяти. Андроид убивает процесс второго плана. Это происходит только если например игрушку какую параллельно запустить. У данного телефона памяти - 1Гб.

Comment: логи приложите, чтобы мы могли видеть причину убийства :)

Comment: оберни в try catch )))

Comment: Попробуйте переопределить `onActivityResult` в активности  и если он будет вызываться, то уже вручную дёргать его в целевом фрагменте или обрабатывать на месте. Но вообще-то по-внимательнее проверьте логи при возвращении из камеры - нет ли ошибок. Я всё-таки думаю, что разработчики Андроида должны были предусмотреть такой вариант, когда приложение перезапущено перед получением результата. Скорее всего вы не используете сохранённый системой фрагмент, а всегда создаёте новый.

Comment: @woesss, заработало, когда перенес обработку ```onActivityResult``` в активность из фрагмента. Хмм, фрагмент похоже не использую сохраненный, а заменяю - ```replace```

Comment: Чтобы использовать сохранённое состояние нужно проверить параметр метода `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` - если он не `null`, то активность/фрагмент восстановлены, но тут есть нюансы - по дефолту сохраняется далеко не всё подряд и это нужно учитывать. Механизм сохранения/восстановления слабо как-то документирован, особенно что там сохраняется по дефолту... Поищите какое-то чтиво по этой теме, а если не сможете разобраться (или лень), то я вам уже предложил два варианта: обработать результат в активности или передать его во фрагмент вручную.

Comment: @woesss, у меня все сохраняется. Проблема похоже была в том, что фрагмент пересоздавался и к нему не поступал результат в ```onActivityResult ```, как вы и сказали.

Answer (score 0):

Основное приложение при нажатии кнопки уходит из состояния onResume в состояние onStop, которое у вас не описано. Больше деталей можно сказать, если увижу код. Если же не хватает оперативной памяти при переходе из одного приложения в другое, то тем более вам необходимо будет переопределить данные методы, что укажу дальше (для сохранения состояния приложения в более компактном варианте, если устройство позволяет - то сохранить в виде временного текстового файла).

Вам необходимо переопределить методы onRestart(),onStart(), onResume(). Если захотите понять больше по вашей ошибке - прочитайте статьи на тему "Жизненный цикл приложений Android"

P.S.:Ниже немного справочной информации:

```
onCreate()– вызывается при первом создании Activity
onStart() – вызывается перед тем, как Activity будет видно пользователю
onResume() – вызывается перед тем как будет доступно для активности пользователя (взаимодействие)

onPause() – вызывается перед тем, как будет показано другое Activity
onStop() – вызывается когда Activity становится не видно пользователю
onDestroy() – вызывается перед тем, как Activity будет уничтожено
```